# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'quiz.jpg' to data type int

Tags: database, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am getting this error in my logs and I really do not know how to solve it.

"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'quiz.jpg' to data type int."

I am currently using ColdFusion 9. It seems that for whatever reason the site is trying to parse an image file into the database or something like that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That looks like you're trying to caste a string (nvarchar) to an integer.  You may want to take a look here:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Variables_26.html. It's for CF8 but should be similar

Comment: Is it possible this is the result of a SQL injection attack? Is there any place in your app where you have an image or text that is 'quiz.jpg'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `<cfqueryparam>`?

I would guess that you may have something like this:

```
<cfquery param value="#myVar#" cfsqltype="cf_sqltype_integer" />
```

the cfsqltype should be cf_sqltype_varchar.

If that is not the case, then please update your post with the offending code. That would be very helpful.

Comment: <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="25" value="#Arguments.articleID#"> This is the code that it is causing the issue.... The above line i got it from my errorLog file not from the code...

Comment: Ok, so check your DB then. Is the column in question (ArticleID?) defined as an Int? It seems odd that you would put the value 'quiz.jpg' into a column called 'ArticleID'

Comment: I fixed it. Somehow some of my articles were getting weird IDs so I added "if not (isNumeric)" on top of the page and it redirects back to the "/" whenever this thing happens... Thanks for the responses

Comment: You should also consider changing your cfqueryparam tag to cf_sqltype="cf_sql_integer". There is no reason to allow a varchar or anything else through if the column is an INT.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need more of the error details like the line of code on which the error occurs or maybe the whole template to be much help. In the absence of more information, Jason's answer seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you may have a query where you are trying to concatenate a nvarchar column with an int column.

Such as

```
SELECT MyString + MyInt FROM MyTable
```

Unfortunatly SQL Server does not implicitly convert integers to varchar for concatenation, so you will need to convert your integer.

```
SELECT MyString + Convert(varchar(20), MyInt) FROM MyTable
```

or

```
SELECT MyString + Cast(MyInt AS varchar(20)) FROM MyTable
```